# Изменение свойства неактивного элемента

Tags: php, битрикс

Не могу изменить свойства неактивного элемента.
При использовании:

```
    CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
    $el = new CIBlockElement;
    $arProps = Array("ACTIVE"=> "Y");
    $res = $el->Update($ELEMENT_ID, $arProps);
```

Ничего не происходит, даже ошибок нет. Если я меняю свое свойство таким образом:

```
CIBlockElement::SetPropertyValuesEx($ELEMENT_ID, false, array($PROPERTY_CODE => '191'));
```

так же не меняется, но стоит элемент сделать активным то, выключение активности кодом выше работает, и меняются пользовательские свойства. Вопрос это я что то делаю не так или битрикс в принципе не может изменять любые свойства неактивных элементов? пс. Просьба не минусовать, дайте коммент что не ясно я дополню вопрос

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, модуль инфоблока подключен в начале файла?

Comment: @SmolinPavel да подключен

Comment: Перехвата событий нет в init.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуй узнать в чём ошибка, возможно мешают какие-нибудь обработчики или обязательные поля, добавь var_dump($res->LAST_ERROR); в конец:

```
 CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
 $el = new CIBlockElement;
 $arProps = Array("ACTIVE"=> "Y");
 $res = $el->Update($ELEMENT_ID, $arProps); 

 var_dump($res->LAST_ERROR);
```